# Isn't using "of my mother's" a pleonasm?

Tags: grammar

In the phrase "She is a friend of my mother's", do we actually need the genitive case? Isn't the preposition enough?

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  So what?

This is called the [double possessive](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/double-possessives-genitives) and is an idiosyncratic part of English grammar. Logically it doesn't make much sense, but logic has little to do with grammar.  The double possessive is correct.

There are many grammar constructions that don't make sense logically.  Why does French require both *ne* and *pas* to form a negative? Why do verbs agree in person and number with their subject?  Why have tense in verbs when a time phrase can give the same information? There are many many constructions that are pleonastic.

The form "She's a friend of my mother." would be equally correct, but the double possessive can be functional in expressions like "a photograph of my friend's"  (a photograph belonging to my friend, not my friend captured in a photograph)

Comment: So are we saying "She's a friend of my mother" is incorrect?

Comment: I have never heard anyone say it and I am pretty sure this  grammatical  feature will be lost in time.

Comment: @WS2 no we are not.... or at least I am not.

Comment: @Quique you've never heard anyone use this kind of double possessive? It's quite common.

Comment: @Leebo, Quiqe's comment has an ambiguous pronoun.  It makes more sense if it refers to "mother" *without* the apostrophe-S. (And yes, I just used two ambiguous pronouns, but in this case all four combinations effectively mean the same thing.)

Comment: @RayButterworth They both seem equally valid to me.